# Excel formula to convert duration from days, hours, mins, secs into total minutes

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hi trying to find the excel formula to convert (days,hours,mins, secs into total minutes) so for instance I have :

- B3=End date and time (07/11/2019 14:38)
- A3=Start date and time (07/11/2019 14:19)
- C3=Duration between the 2 above date&times)
- D3=Output result 0 days 0 hours 19 mins 0 secs

How or what formula can I use to convert D3 into total number of MINUTES. My D3 column has this formula in it `"=INT(B3-A3)&" days "&TEXT(B3-A3,"h"" hrs ""m"" mins""s""sec """`

Comment: For total minutes, are you looking for whole minutes, only, or minutes and decimal fractions of minutes?  To display all larger time units converted to a smaller time unit, you can wrap the smaller time unit placeholder in square brackets (applies only to whole increments of the unit).  So, for example [m] would display 1 hr 5 minutes 20 sec as 65.

Comment: put `=TEXT(C3,"[mm]")` in D3

Comment: Sounds like an answer to me, @Scott. Unless, Angie, you have a special reason to want to explicitly convert days, hours, mins, secs into total minutes?

Comment: Better you write `=MINUTE(B3)-MINUTE(A3)` , you get `19`  or `=(B3-B3)*1440` ☺